# Testing the functionality of a website application

Tags: selenium, web-applications, automated-tests, watir

I developed a web application and moved now to the testing phase. So, I started looking for good tools to test the functionality and cases on the app, after that I found that the best two tools are Watir and Selenium, which one suits best for my app? taking in consideration the need for the tool to have a recording availability of the created cases, a logfile(i.e.console logfile), and screenshot comparison feature

Answer (score 0):

Watir is actually implemented using Selenium to drive the browser so it isn't useful to think of them as separate entities. Watir extends the usefulness of Selenium by making it easier to write and maintain UI tests. Especially if your web application is in Ruby, Watir is an excellent choice for your tests.

(I'm a developer on Watir, and maintain the Ruby bindings for Selenium)

Comment: are bindings for php available in watir?

Comment: can I use Watir to test the app on the localhost server?

Answer (score -1):

Watir, Selenium, Cucumber, PhantomJS are all good tools and in many places they are used in conjunction with each other since they all have different strengths.

Usually, Selenium is not used alone as a comprehensive tool for all situations (but it can be depending on your needs).

Comment: which one can I use to test a webapp on localhost?

Comment: If you are thinking of Cucumber as a testing tool, you are probably using it incorrectly. PhantomJS is a virtual browser and is rarely the right tool for UI testing.

Comment: @Saif Selenium is a pretty safe bet